# Emulator shut down when doing UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()).takeScreenshot(displayPicFile)

Tags: java, android

I want to get screen shot, but my emulator will shut down when run `UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()).takeScreenshot(displayPicFile);`

my sdk version is `25.2.4`.....